# BluetoothStreamConnection issue in BlackBerry - "BtSppRead failed"

Tags: blackberry, bluetooth, inputstream

I faced that issue:
I send to BB some data via Bluetooth,
and on BB side method available() of InputStream shows me, that there are some bytes available.
But when I call method read(), it retrieves an IOException, with following message: BtSppRead failed.

What is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the bluetooth demo samples supplied with the SDK?

Comment: yes, I've checked, everything works now. The problem was from the remote side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, when I'm sending data to BB device, I close socket too quickly.
From desktop side I use WinAPI, so I should use shutdown() for a SOCKET;